# Adding a mast to a house

Tags: electrical

I have to add a two ft. mast to my house.  Could I use a wire connector to add wire so that I do not have to run new wire?  If I can, is there something I can use to allow me to get to the splice if necessary?  Thank you for your help!A

Comment: Is that a lightning ground that you are running with that wire?

Comment: Answer quality might improve if you provide more complete details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending your service entrance and need to use splices, you would also need to use an appropriately sized junction box so the splices are accessible. Without that, you cannot splice them. If it is, indeed, your service entrance, you might be well served to get the assistance of a qualified electrician; it's a place where you do not want to have any occasion to say "oops! I shouldda done that better."

Answer (score 1):

It would be MUCH more work to splice these conductors than to replace the existing riser with a new mast and new conductors. Even though it is only two feet of length it is absolutely not worth considering splicing.

This is a very common issue and replacing the riser with a mast is the only logical option. In fact, depending on the age and condition of the service replacing the meter pan and even service entrance conductors might be worth considering.